# Elasticsearch not mapping logstash date correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I'm using ELK to centralize all our logs and I'm forwarding Artifactory request logs.

This would be a sample line:
`20160615130655|1|REQUEST|123.456.789.012|non_authenticated_user|GET|/9spj7rhd.fts|HTTP/1.1|401|0`

This is the Logstash filter:

```
filter{
        if [type] == 'artifactory-request'{
                grok {
                        'match'         => {"message" => "%{DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG:logtime:string}\|%{NUMBER:request_time}\|%{DATA:request_type}\|%{IP:request_ip}\|%{DATA:request_username}\|%{DATA:request_method}\|%{DATA:resource_path}\|HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\|%{NUMBER:response_code}\|%{NUMBER:size}"}
                        'remove_tag'    => ["_grokparsefailure"]
                }

                date {
                        'match' => ["logtime", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
                }

        }
}
```

Which seems to be working fine, if I look at the Logstash logs I see it's mapping the values correctly:

```
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "@version" => "1",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "@timestamp" => "2016-06-15T13:10:24.000Z",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "file" => "/mnt/artifactory/logs/request.log",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "host" => "artifactory",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "offset" => "4667597",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "type" => "artifactory-request",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "tags" => [],
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "logtime" => "20160615131024",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "request_time" => "1",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "request_type" => "REQUEST",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "request_ip" => "123.456.789.012",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "request_username" => "non_authenticated_user",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "request_method" => "GET",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "resource_path" => "/login.php",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "http_version" => "1.1",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "response_code" => "401",
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: "size" => "0"
Jun 15 13:10:30 elk docker[22890]: }
```

However, ES doesn't seem to like my `logtime` field.

```
Jun 15 13:18:00 elk docker[22580]: [2016-06-15 13:18:00,288][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Stellaris] [logstash-2016.06.15][4] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[logstash-2016.06.15][artifactory-request][AVVUNhxaSE2i6S9oVvq2], source[{"message":"20160615131757|0|REQUEST|123.456.789.012|non_authenticated_user|GET|/|HTTP/1.1|302|0","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-06-15T13:17:57.000Z","file":"/mnt/artifactory/logs/request.log","host":"artifactory","offset":"4668979","type":"artifactory-request","tags":[],"logtime":"20160615131757","request_time":"0","request_type":"REQUEST","request_ip":"123.456.789.012","request_username":"non_authenticated_user","request_method":"GET","resource_path":"/","http_version":"1.1","response_code":"302","size":"0"}]}
Jun 15 13:18:00 elk docker[22580]: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [logtime]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "20160615131757" is malformed at "31757"];
```

Looking at the mappings (which I'm guessing have been generated automatically as I haven't done it) I can see why it doesn't like it

```
"logtime" : {
    "type" : "date",
    "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd||epoch_millis"
}
```

How does ES decide logtime is a date? How can I fix it so it accepts this new format I'm inputing? This used to work before and I haven't really changed anything so I'm quite confused.

This is the only ouput related configuration I have on the Logstash side:

```
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And I haven't changed any configuration on Elasticsearch, I'm using whatever comes by default.

Any ideas please? What am I missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the problem comes from the mapping.

You can transform the logtime field from a string to a date.
With a second date filter, with a target to the logtime field :

```
    date {
            'match' => ["logtime", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
            'target' => "logtime"
    }
```

This will replace the string with a date and the mapping problem won't show up.
The date filter with `'target' => "logtime"` must be placed after the one without, or it won't work.

It's a fix, but you should try to investigate why you have such a mapping. The ES mappings are associated to an index and created when receiving a document.
They depend on the fields of this document.
So it means the first `artifactory-request` document arriving in ES had a date in the field `logtime`. 
Or there is a template in ES that is used to create the index, which associate logtime with the date type.

Comment: Thanks @baudsp. It's now stopped complaining about the previous format and started complaining about the date format of a different log. As a (hopefully) quick fix I've changed the names so now `logtime` is `artifactory_logtime` and so on. Let's see if that's solves my issue while I investigate more.
Thanks for your help!